# Splitting a element in a list into two elements?

Tags: python, list, split

Let's say I have a list and one of the elements is ["1-11"] is there anyway to make the element into ["1", "11"]?

Thanks

Comment: `my_list = my_list[0].split("-")`?

Answer (score 3):

You can split it from (-):

```
li ["1-11"] 
li = li[0].split("-")
```

Output:

```
['1', '11']
```

Comment: This may or may not be satisfactory for OP's needs. I half expect them to say "ok, but what if I want to turn `["1", "2-3", "4-5"]` into `["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]`?" in which case splitting on a single element is no good.

Comment: I was only giving a solution to the specific problem OP mentioned.

Comment: Indeed, and a fine solution it is... I only wish OP had provided more test cases.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have initial object of type `list`, more generic way to achieve this will be:

```
>>> my_list = ["1-11", "2-22"]  # List that holds multiple values of given format
>>> [sub_item for item in my_list for sub_item in item.split("-")]
['1', '11', '2', '22']
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this help

```
data = ["1", "1-2", "3-4", "4-5","6"]

str = "-".join(data)   // "1-1-2-3-4-4-5-6"

result = str.split("-")   // ["1", "1", "2", "3", "4", "4", "5", "6"]
```

1. Join the list with the split indicator (in this case is "-") to become a full string like

> "1-1-2-3-4-4-5-6"

2. Split the string with the split indicator ("-") to convert into list.

> ["1", "1", "2", "3", "4", "4", "5", "6"]

Basically just convert the list into string with **JOIN()** and convert back to list with **SPLIT()** can do the trick.

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Comment: @flamel2p What if it is a combination of "-" and ",". How do you manage?